# Handling TabLayout with multiple scenarios

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm using a `TabLayout` + `ViewPager` to display a few tabs. Depending on a server response, I want to create two possible scenarios: in the first there are three tabs and in the second there are only two, 'removing' the tab in position 0.

Since I'm 'removing' the first tab, all methods that rely on position to perform anything that's related to a specific fragment become outdated and are likely to fail the `instanceof` check.

For example, this is `getItem` in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, which doesn't handle the second scenario at the moment:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    AbstractFragment fragment;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MainFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MessagesFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new SearchFragment();
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Listener example in `MainActivity` (the check will fail in the second scenario):

```
Fragment fragment = viewPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(2);
if (fragment instanceof SearchFragment) {
    ((SearchFragment)fragment).doStuff();

}
```

My only idea is to check the server response (i.e if there are two or three tabs) in every listener in `MainActivity` and in every case in `getItem`, which is a terrible solution in my opinion. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are only few tabs, a good approach would be to make a list of fragments you want to show:

```
List<AbstractFragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
if (showFirstTab) {
    fragments.add(new MainFragment());
}
fragments.add(new MessagesFragment());
fragments.add(new SearchFragment());
```

and then at `getItem` method, do like that:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (fragments.size() > position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When you need to get a specific fragment, you could get the `fragments` list and iterate over it testing the `instanceof`.

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: @NeriaNachum did this solve your problem? If yes, please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom fragment pager adapter to get fragment by position

```
public abstract class FragmentPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "FragmentPagerAdapter";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction mCurTransaction = null;
    private Fragment mCurrentPrimaryItem = null;
    private String mAdapterClassName;

    protected FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String adapterClassName) {
        mFragmentManager = fm;
        mAdapterClassName = adapterClassName;
    }

    /**
     * Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.
     */
    protected abstract Fragment getItem(int position);

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }

        // Do we already have this fragment?
        String name = makeFragmentTag(position);
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
        if (fragment != null) {
            mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
        } else {
            fragment = getItem(position);
            mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                    makeFragmentTag(position));
        }
        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(false);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        if (mCurTransaction == null) {
            mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        mCurTransaction.detach((Fragment) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
            if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
                mCurrentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
                fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
            }
            mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        if (mCurTransaction != null) {
            mCurTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            mCurTransaction = null;
            mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return ((Fragment) object).getView() == view;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    /**
     * Return a unique identifier for the item at the given position.
     * <p/>
     * <p>The default implementation returns the given position.
     * Subclasses should override this method if the positions of items can change.</p>
     *
     * @param position Position within this adapter
     * @return Unique identifier for the item at position
     */
    private long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public String makeFragmentTag(int position) {
        return "purplle:switcher:" + mAdapterClassName + ":" + position;
    }

    public static String makeFragmentTag(int position,String adapterClassName) {
        return "purplle:switcher:" + adapterClassName + ":" + position;
    }
}
```

Now just  extend your  viewPager adapter class by `FragmentPagerAdapter`

to get the fragment in your activity.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mPagerAdapter.makeFragmentTag(0) //Postion of fragment to access
```